# Add module to React Native - error: cannot find symbol

Tags: android, react-native

I want to add a simple module to my React Native app. But I have an errors:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavacE:\project\android\app\src\main\java\com\androiddepends\HelloWorld.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
    ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class HelloWorld
E:\project\android\app\src\main\java\com\androiddepends\HelloWorld.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                        ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class HelloWorld
E:\project\android\app\src\main\java\com\androiddepends\HelloWorld.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable Intent
  location: class HelloWorld
E:\project\android\app\src\main\java\com\androiddepends\HelloWorld.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                               ^
  symbol:   method getPackageManager()
  location: class HelloWorld
4 errors
 FAILED
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.androiddepends;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import android.util.Log;

public class HelloWorld extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public HelloWorld(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "HelloWorld";
    } 

    @ReactMethod
    public void openWifiSettings() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should import android SDK's intent package which is not found in the imports section.

> android.content.Intent

the problem is SDK's Intent class is not found.

Comment: Doesn't work. I added `import android.content.Intent;` and still the same errors.

Comment: just clean and rebuild it if it works. are you using android studio setup or other setup i.e atom and command line tools?

Comment: I used PHPStrom, but I just move my project to Android Studio. How to rebuild React Native project in Android Studio?

Comment: Just go to build menu Build -> Rebuild Project